# COMO CHAMAR O https://www.domin.com/?textonome

Tags: php, javascript, html

COMO CHAMAR O https://www.domin.com/?OlaMundo em php html javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Melhora a tua pergunta. Não dá para entender a dúvida.

Comment: Bem-vindo Davidson BPE, posts importantes para você ler https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485 e leia ese também https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$partes = explode("?",$uri); //Divide uma string em strings

echo $partes{1};
```

- **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** - O URI fornecido para acessar a página atual

  Exemplos

  1:  `https://www.dominio.com/?OlaMundo` 
  vai retornar `/?OlaMundo`

  2: `https://www.dominio.com/dir1/pag.php?OlaMundo` retorna `dir1/pag.php?OlaMundo`
- **explode()**  retorna uma matriz de strings, cada uma como substring de string formada pela divisão dela a partir do ? (ponto de interrogação).

exemplo `Array ( [0] => dir1/pag.php [1] => OlaMundo )`

finalmente você o segundo elemento do array `$partes{1}`

Answer (score 0):

Em JavaScript:

```
location.href.split('?').pop();
```

Exemplo (onde `url_` seria a URL da página):

```js
url_ = "http://www.dominio.com/livro.html?olamundo";
alert(url_.split('?').pop()); // exibe "olamundo"
```

Ou usando `lastIndexOf`:

```
url_ = location.href;
url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("?")+1, url_.length);
```

Exemplo (onde `url_` seria a URL da página):

```js
url_ = "http://www.dominio.com/livro.html?olamundo";
alert(url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("?")+1, url_.length)); // exibe "olamundo"
```